# Is it possible to set prefetch count on @RabbitListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I know it is possible to make `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean and set prefetch count and message listener here, like this:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(
        ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory,
        Receiver receiver) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("hello");
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receive"));
    container.setPrefetchCount(1000);
    return container;
}
```

But how to set prefetch count for channel if I want to use declarative approach using `@RabbitListener`?

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "hello") // how to set prefetch count here?
    public void receive(String message) {
        log.info(" [x] Received '{}'.", message);
    }

}
```

It is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@RabbitListener` has `containerFactory` option:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 * @return the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

Where you can configure `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` with the desired `prefetchCount` and the target `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for that annotation will have that option for you.

Comment: If you are using the default container factory created by Spring Boot, you can set the property in application.yml or application.properties - see `spring.rabbitmq.listener.prefetch` in the [boot properties appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: @GaryRussell,The documentation doesn't mention any default value. If this is not set, do you know the prefetch size?

Comment: 250 in recent versions - see the [Spring AMQP reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#containerAttributes).

Answer (score 22):

**Solution according to @artem-bilan answer:**

Declare `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean with prefetch count 10 in some `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> prefetchTenRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(10);
    return factory;
}
```

`Receiver` bean uses this factory bean:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "hello", containerFactory = "prefetchTenRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(String message) {
        log.info(" [x] Received '{}'.", message);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "hello")
    public void receiveWithoutPrefetch(String message) {
        log.info(" [x] Received without prefetch '{}'.", message);
    }

}
```

Two listeners here is just for demo purpose.
With this configuration Spring creates two AMQP channels. One for each `@RabbitListener`. First with prefetch count 10 using our new `prefetchTenRabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean and second with prefetch count 1 using default `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean.

Comment: If you are using the default container factory created by Spring Boot, you can set the property in application.yml or application.properties - see `spring.rabbitmq.listener.prefetch` in the [boot properties appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Spring boot 2.3.3 and I changed the following in application.properties and it worked.

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.prefetch=1000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1000
```

I don't know the difference between direct and simple so I set both.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434549/rabbit-spring-boot-properties

Comment: These refer to the Types of listener container you can declare in Spring. The docs here give more information. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#container

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different prefetch for each queue you can create listener factory with default spring setting and override just prefetch.

```
@Bean
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> prefetchRabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(prefetch);
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        int concurrentConsumers = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLoader.getProperty("queue.concurrent-consumers"));
        int maxConcurrentConsumers = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLoader.getProperty("queue.max-concurrent-consumers"));
        int consecutiveActiveTrigger = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLoader.getProperty("queue.consecutive-active-trigger"));
        int prefectCount = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLoader.getProperty("queue.prefetch_count"));

        factory.setPrefetchCount(prefectCount);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
        factory.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(consecutiveActiveTrigger);
        return factory;
    }
```