# Rabbit Spring Boot properties

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-rabbit

What is the key difference between the following properties :

1)spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.prefetch= # Number of messages to be handled in a single request. It should be greater than or equal to the transaction size (if used).

2)spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch= # Number of messages to be handled in a single request. It should be greater than or equal to the transaction size (if used).

Answer (score 5):

With Spring AMQP 1.7.x and earlier (boot 1.5.x uses that version), there was only one listener container (`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`).

Spring AMQP introduced a new listener container (the `DirectMessageListenerContainer`); boot therefore, now, has 2 sets of properties, depending on which property you choose.

Actually, the help for the `...direct...` property is incorrect since that container does not support transaction size.

The `prefetch` represents how many unacknowledged messages are allowed at each consumer. The simple container's `transaction-size` represents how many messages are processed before a transaction is committed; it also represents how many messages are processed before an `ack` is sent.

See [the Spring AMQP documentation for more information about these properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these properties were applicable in older version of spring boot
When I used this documentation specific to the version 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
then only this property is available :
spring.rabbitmq.listener.prefetch= # Number of messages to be handled in a single request. It should be greater than or equal to the transaction size (if used).